# How to edit an ArrayList without editing previous versions?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working with a 2D array of arrayLists (I'm trying to create a Sudoku solver).
I want to edit individuals arrayLists.

```java
ArrayList<Integer>[][] sudWork = new ArrayList[9][9];
ArrayList<Integer> oneToNine = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=1;i< 10;i++){
    oneToNine.add(i);
}
for(int i=0;i< 9;i++){
    for(int j=0;j< 9;j++){
        sudWork[i][j]=oneToNine;
    }
}
Print2DArr(sudWork);

int x=(int)(Math.random()*sudWork[0][0].size())+1;
sudWork[0][0].clear();
sudWork[0][0].add(x);
System.out.println(sudWork[0][2]);
Print2DArr(sudWork);
```

With this I am hoping to change the list in [0][0] to a single number, then remove that number from all arrayLists in rows and columns 0.

Instead the clear and add methods seem to be applying to the entire 2D array, rather than just sudWork[0][0].

Comment: You are adding the same `ArrayList` instance to all the indexes of your array .Consider having distinct objects at the different indexes.

Comment: @Arnaud can't I still edit the instances after doing so? I assume you mean oneToNine?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the same object is everywhere, if you edit it, you edit it everywhere.

Comment: I see. So I should create an Arraylist like oneToNine within the loop, and then make sudWork[i][j] equal to that? (if I'm making sense)

Comment: Yes, you should definetly create and store a new object at each iteration .

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want something like that. Move creating of oneToNine to for loop.

```
for(int i=0;i< 9;i++){
    for(int j=0;j< 9;j++){
        ArrayList<Integer> oneToNine = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int u=1;u< 10;u++){
            oneToNine.add(u);
        }
        sudWork[i][j]=oneToNine;
    }
}
```

You can also stay at your first version but in loop create copy of list:

```java
ArrayList<Integer> oneToNine = new ArrayList<>();
for(int u=1;u< 10;u++){
  oneToNine.add(u);
}

ArrayList<Integer>[][] sudWork = new ArrayList[9][9];
for(int i=0;i< 9;i++){
  for(int j=0;j< 9;j++){

      sudWork[i][j]= new ArrayList<>(oneToNine);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep exactly. Thank you!